# Cannot send a variable through Angular 5 HttpClient Post to insert it in database using PHP

Tags: php, angular, post, httpclient, angular5

I want to insert a field in my database using Angular 5 and PHP.

I started by adding a new function inside my `api.ts` file:

```
public partnerName: String;
constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }

addPartners(partnerName)
{
    return this.http.post('http://aff.local/addPartners.php', this.partnerName).pipe(map(
    res=>{
      console.log(res)
    }
  ))
}
```

This function will take a value from text box and send it to php file, having the following script:

```
public function addPartner($partner_name){
    global $conn;
    $addParner = "INSERT INTO partner(partner_name, partner_image) VALUES(:partner_name, '')";
    $execAddPartner = $conn->prepare($addParner);
    $execAddPartner->bindValue(":partner_name", $partner_name);
    $execAddPartner->execute();

    return true;
}
```

And the I will run the function into the URL specified in my `.post` function:

```
<?php
require_once('affiliatePartner.php');
$partnerName = $_POST['partnerName'];
$aff = new affiliatePartner;

$result = $aff->addPartner($partnerName);
echo $result;
?>
```

Now, when the subscribe button is clicked I will run the function:

```
addPartner(){
    this.email = this.subscribeForm.get('emailTxt').value;
    this.api.addPartners(this.email).subscribe(
  (data)=>{
    console.log(data);
  },
  (error)=>{
    console.log(error)
  }
  );
 }
```

In this method, I am calling the addPartner() method from my api file, that I have already imported it to the component.ts file.

On the HTML part, I have the button:

```
<button [disabled]="subscribeForm.invalid" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit" 
(click)="addPartner();">Subscribe 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signin">

<input 
type="email" 
id="email" 
class="form-control input-sm chat-input mr-sm-2 text-warning font-weight-bold fontSizeSubs" 
placeholder="Email" 
formControlName="emailTxt">
```

When I click on button, I am having a server side error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'partner_name' cannot be null' in
>   C:\wamp64\www\aff\affiliatePartner.php on line 28

Which means, that the variable is not send by Angular at all. So the problem, is how to send the variable to php script.

At the console, I had this message when I click button:

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText:
>   "OK", url: "http://aff.local/addPartner.php", ok: false, …}

[image]

Comment: did you try sending you var with get request???

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov Yep. Still the same error.

Comment: Dear friend, you can use postman for testing purpose of your APIs: https://www.getpostman.com/. Try to send your POST request using POSTMAN.

Comment: I send the variable through the url, and get it in php using `$_request` and it works fine. But the post method is not working.

Comment: Your front-end (FE) & back-end (BE) on the different servers? Your url is absolute. If your FE & BE is running on the same server then you should set relative url to php script. Furthermore it's might be cause of CORS.